# How to concatenate a variable and string inside a prop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
<TextField
          label="First Name"
          defaultValue="My name is" + ${name}
/>
```

Here, `name` is the variable storing the actual name. I need to concatenate it with the string "My name is". `$` doesn't work. I get an error at '+' saying *identifier expected*.

Comment: How about just `defaultValue="My name is" + name`? (Or a template literal as in the answer)

Comment: Are you using react?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using react, you can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<TextField
  label="First Name"
  defaultValue={`My name is ${name}`}
/>
```

Comment: I think you should remove the " and +,  this should be {`My name is ${name}`}

Comment: Won't this output `My name is" + Frank`?

Comment: @LW001 yes. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do like this

```
<TextField
    label="First Name"
    defaultValue={"My name is " + name}
/>
```